# Cancel a click event in ShowDialog form

Tags: c#

I am displaying a form using `xForm.ShowDialog(this);`.

This form has a button which has its `DialogResult` set to OK. Now when I click on the OK button, there is some validation performed. If it fails I want the form to remain as it but but the form closes and returns an `DialogResult.OK` to the main form. So how do I prevent that from happening?

For e.g.

```
Button_click
{
    If validation fails pretend we never came here
    else some code.. return DialogResult.OK
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't assign a DialogResult to the button. A Method that returns a DialogResult can be used that calls the Form.ShowDialog method. If the Validate button is hit, validate the form and if the validation succeeds return the expected DialogResult.

Answer (score 3):

```
Button_click()
{
  if (this.Validate())
  {
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK ;
  }

}
```

Comment: Nice.  But I think you mean:   this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

Answer (score 0):

In your dialog's FormClosing event, set FormClosingEventArgs Cancel property to true if you don't want the form to close.